# Why does this min() call work for dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the key of the smallest element in a dictionary.

```py
dictionary = {'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 8}
```

I should get 'a' as the key.

There was this piece of code that I found but I'm not really sure how it works.

```py
def key_of_min_value(d):
    print(min(d, key=d.get))
```

I'm confused on what `key = d.get` means while I'm assuming the `min(d, ...)` part is saying that it's getting the minimum element in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The word "key" is a bit overloaded here.  The key passed to `min`, i.e. `d.get`, is a callable which is used to transform the values before the comparison. There is a similar `key` argument for the built-in function `sorted`.

This "key" is unrelated to the word "key" as used when referring to the keys/values of dictionaries.

So the code works by iterating to find the `k` in the dictionary for which `d.get(k)` is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

> **min(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])**:
>
> > Return the smallest item in an iterable or the smallest of two or more arguments.
> >     If one positional argument is provided, it should be an iterable. The smallest item in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional arguments are provided, the smallest of the positional arguments is returned.
> >
> > There are two optional keyword-only arguments. The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort(). The default argument specifies an object to return if the provided iterable is empty. If the iterable is empty and default is not provided, a ValueError is raised.

It's important to understand that `min` operates by iterating through the argument and (without specifying a key) returns the "lowest" ranked value. Comparisons are done with the `<, >, etc.` operators. When you pass in a callable as `key`, the individual elements will be used as an argument to this function.

To break this down some more, this is (more-or-less) what is happening when you call `min(d, key=d.get)`:

```py
lowest_val = None
lowest_result = None
for item in d:
    if lowest_val is None or d.get(item) < lowest_val:
        lowest_val = d.get(item)  # These are the elements we are comparing
        lowest_result = item  # But this is the element we are 'returning'
print(f"The min value (result of the callable key) is '{lowest_val}'")
print(f"The min item corresponding to the min value is '{lowest_result}'")
```

Notice we don't compare each `item`, but we compare the result of whatever the callable key is, when `item` is used as an argument.